# backbone this.model.set is not working

Tags: backbone.js

for some reason, this.model is not working in my editUsp method. I want to change the values in the model with .set.

Does anybody know, what i'm doing wrong?

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'set'
```

This is the code:

```
var Usp = Backbone.Model.extend();

var widgetView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Usp,
    initialize: function (data,collection) {
        var usp = new Usp({type:'usp', items: data});
        collection.add(usp);
        this.render(data);
    },
    events: {
            "click .edit":   "editUsp",
    },
    editUsp: function(){
        this.model.set({type:'uspsss',items: 'hoi'});
    },
    render: function(data){
        var uspList = '<ul>';
        $.each(data['Usps'], function(i,item){
            uspList += '<li>'+item+'</li>';
        });
        var template = _.template('<div class="block"><a class="edit"><i class="icon-edit"></i> Edit </a><%= uspList %></div>');
        var widgetView = template({uspList: uspList});
        this.setElement(widgetView);
        $('.laySidebar .smallBlocks').append($(this.el).hide().fadeIn(700));
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to an instance of your model in your view.

For example:

```
var usp = new Usp();
```

Now you have one instance of your model. Pass it to your view instance

```
var widgetViewInstance = new widgetView({model: usp});
```

Remove the following line from your widgetView definition:

```
model: Usp,
```

Rest should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Backbone.Model.extend(...)` in the first line, try this instead...

`var Usp = new Backbone.Model();`

`extend(...)` is just extending the Backbone.Model class. To do a `set`, you need an instance of the Model.